# How to determine time-invariance from input-output pairs?

Tags: signal-processing

This is the question:

[image]

And this is the solution:

[image]

I really have no idea how this solution is reached.

I see that when x1 and x2 are added, I get the inputs {0, 1, 0}, with 1 being sample 0 (dirac delta function). I then see how y1 and y2 added produce {0, 3, -1, 2, 1}.

However, It really makes no sense how it can be told that y3 (response to x3) would be
{3, 2, 1, 3, 1} if the system was time invariant. It seems like a massive leap. I could *maybe* see how the solution is reached if x3 were a time-shifted version of x1 + y2, but it isn't

Right now, we have x1 + x2 = {0, 1, 0} and

x3 = {0, 1, 1}.

x3 isn't a time-shifted version of x1 + x2. Due to this, It makes no sense to me why y3 is what determines that the system is time-variant

Answer (score 0):

`x1[n] + x2[n] + x1[n-1] + x2[n-1] = x3[n]` (two impulses)

Therefore if the system was time invariant `y3[n]` should equal `y1[n] + y2[n] + y1[n-1] + y2[n-1]` which is `{0 ,3 ,-1 ,2 ,1 ,0} + {0, 0, 3, -1, 2, 1} = {0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1}`

As it doesn't, the system is not time invariant.